# How show rational simplification?

Tags: fractions, cancel

I need to show the path to simplify fractions, i.e., through their common divisors, so that show the first simplifications. For example:
18/6
I'd want to show some like this:

```
\frac{\cancel{18}^9}{\cancel{6}_3}
```

Taking 2 as a common divisor, I want that the 9 and the 3 appear above/below of 18 and 6 respectively. If I have more divisors they appear above/below of previous, for example, 50:

```
\cancel{50}^{\cancel{10}^{2}}
```

i.e., I want that 10 appears above of the cancelled 50, the 2 appear above of the cancelled 10 (if I divide for 5)

Is there some command or package that does that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE! There is a package named `cancel` which does what you want!

Comment: Please can you provide a minimal working example putting, if possible, an hand-drawing of that you want?

Comment: Thanks Dan for your help. It's work fine.
I modified a little the command using \cancel, because is more beauty, for example:
\cancelmcd{24}{\cancelmcd{12}{\cancelmcd{6}{3}}}
where \cancelmcd is a new command defined as:
\newcommand{\cancelmcd}[2]{\substack{#2\\\text{\cancel{#1}}}}

Sorry by my bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `\substack` and `\sout` from `ulem` you could do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\frac{\substack{9\\\text{\sout{18}}}}{\substack{\text{\sout{6}}\\3}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can keep adding lines to the stack, so you can have multiple divisors if you want.

Comment: I reviewed the modification above mentioned a bit because wasn't behaving quite as he expected, especially in the denominator. Searching in documents and manuals, I see the command `overset` and `underset`. I used like this: `\overset{3}{\overset{\cancel{9}}{\cancel{27}}}`, similarly for `\underset`. The new command was left this way:
`\newcommand[2]{\cancelnum}{\overset{#1}{\cancel{#2}}}`
`\newcommand[2]{\cancelden}{\underset{#1}{\cancel{#2}}}`
when #1 is the new number and #2 is the canceled number.

Answer (score 2):

As suggest @Imran in his comment - use of `cancel` package do this:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}
$\frac{\cancel{50}^{~5}}{\cancel{10}^{~1}} = 5$
\end{document}
```

[image]